# Is ca_certs_filename part of sp_session_config struct or not?

Tags: spotify, libspotify

According to doxygen generated data on [developer.spotify.com](http://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.51/structsp__session__config.html) there is a ca_certs_filename in the sp_session_config struct. 
This is not found in struct defined in api.h

Does it exist or not? 
Is there a version incompatibility?

Answer (score 0):

On version 12.1.103 for armv6hf yes, otherwise no.

Comment: Thanks! (need 15 reps to set as "useful")